# mongodb collection sort string filed by numeric order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have collection with numeric value in string format. I want to get distinct value sorted by numeric order.

Here is the sample data and query I have https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z9VRzlHjD7J

**Data**

```
[
  {
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "1005"
  },
  {
    id: "50"
  },
  {
    id: "110"
  },
  {
    id: "1157"
  },
  {
    id: "9"
  },
  {
    id: "447"
  },
  
]
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "1005"
  },
  {
    "_id": "110"
  },
  {
    "_id": "1157"
  },
  {
    "_id": "447"
  },
  {
    "_id": "50"
  },
  {
    "_id": "9"
  }
]
```

How can I sort this value by numeric order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      intId: {
        $toInt: "$id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      intId: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collation` to sort numeric strings as numbers in MongoDB.
A `collation` document has to the following fields:

```
{
  locale: <string>,
   caseLevel: <boolean>,
   caseFirst: <string>,
   strength: <int>,
   numericOrdering: <boolean>,
   alternate: <string>,
   maxVariable: <string>,
   backwards: <boolean>
}
```

Note, when you use collation, the locale field is mandatory and all other fields are optional.

Example:

```
db.collection.find().sort({id:1}).collation({locale:"en_US", numericOrdering:true};
```

Comment: @sfgroups you can find more info here: https://www.sneppets.com/mongodb/how-to-sort-numeric-strings-as-numbers-in-mongodb/

Comment: this didn't work in mongo playground, but it worked on my local database. error in version 6. `Invalid query:

Line 1: Unsupported method: only find(), aggregate(), update() and explain() are supported`